# Autorización laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estoy realizando una autorización con el siguiente código

```
Route::post('/post', function () {
    // The current user may create posts...
})->middleware('can:create,App\Post');
```

el cual funciona bien lo único es que me arroja un mensaje de estado 403 donde podría cambiar esto para que me redireccione y mostrar una notificación mediante un mensaje de session.

Comment: o seria mas conveniente crear la validación desde un middleware y agregar todo lo antes mencionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El manejo de errores se hace a través de `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, en la clase Handler. Para gestionar un error de autorización, por ejemplo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof 
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized.'], 403);
            }

            return response()->view('base.errors.403');
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Más información en la documentación oficial: [Gestor de Excepciones (Español)](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/errors#the-exception-handler)